# Search within opened file in Xcode without Apple keyboard

Tags: keyboard, xcode, icon, search

Is there a way to search within opened file (only!) in Xcode when I can not use Apple keyboard (because I am connecting remotely via LogMeIn from a PC)? I guess there was a search icon just above the text editor in Xcode 4.3 but I can not find it in 4.6.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how an Apple keyboard affects it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to access the search function through the **Edit** menu. Select **Edit > Find > Find...**

[image]

The search box will appear for the currently selected file:

[image]